# How to host the flutter view in the native view of the flutter app?

Tags: flutter

How to host the flutter view in the native view of the flutter app?

Because when I was developing the flutter plug-in, I found that some SDKs allow customizing native views.

I think if the flutter view can be hosted in the native view of the flutter application, then when the plug-in is used on the flutter side, the flutter view can be dynamically passed to the native view without the need to predefine the native view in the native view.